# Using `screen` and PHP's built-in web server

Tags: gnu-screen, raspberry-pi, webserver

I have a Raspberry Pi set up to run a PHP web application. For reasons that I won't go into right now, my current efforts involve using PHP's build-in web server:

```
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

To get it going I connect to the Pi via SSH, run the `php` command via `screen` so that I can disconnect from the SSH connection and the web server will carry on running.

It works for a little while, but then some time (hours) later the Pi has generally crashed.

Is this typical of `screen`? What might be causing the crash?

Comment: What makes you think screen caused the crash?

Comment: A fair question, I can't remember now if I did a longer test without `screen` in play and just maintained an SSH connection to the Pi.

Comment: I think `screen` is overkill for this purpose.  I would log in via ssh, start `php` in the background via `nohup` with error and output redirected to a file.  `nohup php -S localhost:8000 > php.out 2>&1 &`.  Then you can log out and the php server continues running.  You can also look at `php.out` with `less` or `tail -f` to see the progress.  This is much simpler than running `screen` and may eliminate some variables in your quest to determine the cause of the crash.

Comment: I have a raspberry pi clone, and honestly some things wont go that far with a MicroSD card. Nowadays I am using it with an SSD disk after ruining 2 or 3 cards in a very short time. The idea of running any kind of web server generating logs in a card it is not the best of the ideas. Better redirect it to /dev/null